# Benchmarking Hadoop - Why do reads take as long as replicated writes?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, benchmarking

I have a 16 node cluster with a replication factor of 2 with Hadoop 1.0.4. I have set the maximum number of map and reduce tasks to 1, and I have disabled speculative task execution.

I am running the TestDFSIO benchmark to create workloads that burden each node on the cluster evenly. I perform the following sequence:

1. TestDFSIO write 48 files of 2GB
2. Drop the caches on each node in the cluster to prevent data from being read from memory
3. TestDFSIO read the 48 files of 2GB.

In each of these workloads, every node in the 16-node cluster should ideally see 3 data-local map tasks.

Because the writes are 2-replicated, I would expect the write workload to take about twice as long as the read workload (minus any warmup and cooldown associated with mapreduce). Instead, writes and reads take about the **same** amount of time.

A few clues:

1. Invariably, the "splits" when starting up the job do not cover all of the nodes, so there is a locality_wait_factor of < 1 (usually .75-.9).
2. There are a few rack-local maps when the maps should seemingly all be data-local (I'm assuming this is a consequence of #2).

Why do reads take as long as writes in this case?

Why are there rack-local map tasks when I am doing a TestDFSIO write of only one map at a time?

Assuming it will improve my result, how can I ensure more data locality?